# Clicking on Ajax links twice doesn't work as expected (Cake PHP)

Tags: jquery, ajax, cakephp-1.3

In my Cake PHP application, users can add a team to their watchlist. I have made adding and removing to watchlist Ajax operation using JQuery JsHelper. Both operations work fine independently.

However when a user adds a team to watchlist (works fine) and immediately clicks on remove from watchlist link, it loads the remove view only instead of updating the div without refreshing the page. But after adding a team to watchlist, user clicks on some other links (non-ajax) and then tries to remove the team from watchlist, it works fine.

I assume something is not being updated correctly when user add to watchlist and immediately remove from watchlist. Below is the controller and view code for both actions.

#### CONTROLLER CODE

```
    function add($team_id = null) {
    if(!$team_id)   {
        $this->Session->setFlash(__('Invalid team', true));
        $this->redirect(array('controller' => 'teams', 'action' => 'index'));
    }

    $this->data['Watchlist']['team_id'] = $team_id;
    $this->data['Watchlist']['user_id'] = $this->Auth->user('id');      
    $this->Watchlist->create();
    $this->Watchlist->save($this->data);
    $this->set('current_city', $this->Cookie->read('_current_cityid'));
    $this->set('watchlist_id', $this->Watchlist->id);
    $this->render('add', 'ajax');
}

function remove($id = null) {
    if (!$id) {
        $this->Session->setFlash(__('Invalid ID for watchlist', true));
        $this->redirect(array('controller' => 'team', 'action' => 'index'));
    }
    $this->Watchlist->delete($id); 
    $this->set('current_city', $this->Cookie->read('_current_cityid'));
    $this->set('watchlist_id', $id);
    $this->render('remove', 'ajax');
}
```

#### View Code

```
//add.ctp    
<?php echo $this->Js->link(__('Unwatch', true), array('controller' => 'watchlists', 'action' => 'remove', $watchlist_id), array('class' => 'btn', 'update' => '#watch-btn'));?>

//remove.ctp
<?php echo $this->Js->link(__('Watch this Team', true), array('controller' => 'watchlists', 'action' => 'add', $watchlist_id), array('class' => 'btn', 'update' => '#watch-btn'));?>
```

Any help in the matter would be highly appreciated. If the problem is not clear then please let me know.

#### JQuery Code

//After clicking on 'Add to watchlist' - Link ID incorrect

```
<a id="link-1577632165" class="btn" href="/watchlists/remove/4e96d2ca-9a10-409d-b7f5-0a4507063618">Unwatch</a>

//<![CDATA[
$(document).ready(function () {$("#link-1949180817").bind("click", function (event) {$.ajax({dataType:"html", success:function (data, textStatus) {$("#watch-btn").html(data);}, url:"\/watchlists\/add\/4e7c5af6-7110-426a-80d4-062207063618"});
return false;});});
//]]>
```

//After reloading the page 'Add to watchlist' - Link IDs are correct

```
<a id="link-1441882285" class="btn" href="/watchlists/remove/4e96d31b-b600-4df3-9e86-1cb107063618">Unwatch</a>

//<![CDATA[
$(document).ready(function () {$("#link-1441882285").bind("click", function (event) {$.ajax({dataType:"html", success:function (data, textStatus) {$("#watch-btn").html(data);}, url:"\/watchlists\/remove\/4e96d31b-b600-4df3-9e86-1cb107063618"});
return false;});});
//]]>
```

Comment: I noticed you tagged this with jquery as well. I'm not familiar with cakephp but could you also post your jquery code as it might help someone see something there (in case it's to do with binding the events or something similar)

Comment: Thanks Tommy. Here is the JQuery code. I noticed an issue here if I have clicked on add to watchlist already. Link ID is not correct but why, I am not sure. May be the page need to reload before the ID are correctly formed.

Comment: After looking at JQuery code, one thing is clear. The div is updated however the new Jquery ajax link (for removing team from watchlist) is not being updated. Do I need to pre-load Jquery for both the links in page .. if so, how? But I guess links are dynamically generated everything an action is performed so not sure if pre-loading the links will work. I am soooo confused :-(

Comment: can you not assign data attributes to the links and assign them all a particular class? Then you could use   $('a.mylink').live("click",function(e)){ // your code here});

Comment: Thanks Tommy. I know PHP and Cake PHP but I am not a JS/Jquery expert so I didn't understand what you said. However I was able to fix the issue by setting buffering to false.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those who may encounter this issue - solution to this problem was to set buffer to false in $options array of JsHelper link method call.